# Does Sitecore Personalize replace my current Sitecore CMS

Tags: sitecore

we currently use Sitecore 9.x CMS and are looking to adopt Sitecore Personalize/CDP

Does Sitecore Personalize/CDP replace our Sitecore 9.x CMS or do they work together

If it  is a replacement then our Project Managers have a bigger job on their hands than they currently think

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Personalize/CDP is not a CMS. It's a CDP, Customer Data Platform.
You use it for personalization, profiling and can use that to create various experiences directly - or use it to feed that data to other systems as well as gathering data from other system so you get a full view/profile of the users/customers.
You should more compare sitecore CDP to personalization in Sitecore XP/xDB.

So you can use Sitecore CDP with you current Sitecore XP is you want to. Note that Sitecore CDP can be used with any platform basically, also non-Sitecore.